# How can I update the .sql file through SQL procedure?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a .sql file which has insert queries. I will have to change the insert queries (basically all the ID's need to be reset in query) and then execute.

I have tried by reading .sql file and try to  get the id but here I am not sure what will be the old id at that time. How do I find the old ID and replace with new?

Can anyone suggest me how I can achieve this?

This is my java and pl/sql code:

```
ArrayDescriptor des = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("OFSA.ARRAY_TABLE", con);
ARRAY array_to_pass = new ARRAY(des,con,array);
st = con.prepareCall("call OFSA.proc_test(?,?,?)");
st.setArray(1, array_to_pass);
st.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
st.registerOutParameter(3,OracleTypes.ARRAY,"OFSA.ARRAY _TABLE");
st.execute();
```

plsql code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_TEST(P_ARRAY  IN ARRAY_TABLE,
                                  LEN      OUT NUMBER,
                                  OP_ARRAY OUT ARRAY_TABLE) AS
 V_COUNT NUMBER;
 BEGIN
   OP_ARRAY := NEW ARRAY_TABLE();
   OP_ARRAY.EXTEND(50);
   LEN := P_ARRAY.COUNT;

   FOR I IN 1 .. P_ARRAY.COUNT LOOP
```

Here i Will have to replace the old id with new id. But the query is in a string. and i don't know the exact location where my id is.. and some queries can have multiple id as well. here i need to find the id and replace with new.

Comment: why do you want to do something like that? Isnt it better to pass that id as an argument to the stored procedure?

Comment: what is your dbms ? , also can you show your code ?

Comment: at this time i am not sure how many id's will be there in the .sql ... it will be depends on the application specific objects. i will not have any idea how many ids will be there.

Comment: @pooja...Sorry your question is not clear..So can you share your code.

Comment: This is my java and pl/sql code

Comment: ArrayDescriptor des =           ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("OFSA.ARRAY_TABLE", con);
            ARRAY array_to_pass = new ARRAY(des,con,array);            
            st = con.prepareCall("call OFSA.proc_test(?,?,?)");        
            st.setArray(1, array_to_pass); 
            st.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
             st.registerOutParameter(3,OracleTypes.ARRAY,"OFSA.ARRAY _TABLE");
            st.execute();

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

**Don't use a stored procedure**

Your question is tagged Java.  Just create the insert queries you need in Java and run them directly, avoiding the procedure altogether.  A stored procedure is mainly for cases where you want to *easily re-run the same code*.  If you want different code each time, a procedure is probably not for you.

**Don't hard code the IDs in the stored procedure**

Instead, pass the IDs into the procedure in some manner.

If the insert statements act on a single ID, you can simply pass it in as a parameter, then use that in the query.

If the procedure needs to use a list of IDs, there may be a way to pass in an array (depending on your DB).  Another option is to store the IDs in a table, and make the procedure use this table.  Then you can update the table before calling the procedure.

Comment: Thanks For quick response !!! I will have to change the ids before insert. How i can do that?

Comment: reading .sql file and strong into an string array and passing that array to procedure. In procedure i am trying to read each query and trying to reset the ids and then execute. This how i am trying to do. But i am not getting how do i reset the ids in procedure.

Comment: @pooja, please update your question with additional detail, including *why you need to do this.*  Still not clear.

Comment: Thanks in advance!!!. Basically application related data will be moving from one to another environment(its basically it have some insert queries and  ID are sequence) if i insert as is it will fail with unique key constraint ., so i will have to reset the new id's(separate code to generate the new ids) and then insert into the target environment.  This is what my requirement.